# rsync don't sync the sub folders?

Tags: rsync

`rsync` only syncs the files in my note folder, but not the sub folders or the files in the sub folders. This is my command:

```sh
rsync -a --progress --size-only --exclude=".DS_Store" --exclude=".swp" \
--exclude=".Trash"  --exclude="logs/*" --exclude="xmlogs/*" \
/Users/Devric/Documents/notes/ /Volumes/backup/
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just replicated your chosen flags and the sync went OK between my source and destination folders.
Let's just refresh your memory:

-a stands for *all* which implies the following flags:
-rlptgoD (recurse, copy symlinks, preserve permissions, preserve file times, preserve group, preserve owner, and preserve devices and special files, respectively)

Thus your needed recursion is already taken for,
only problem I've noticed is your last exclude having an extra space,
try:

```
rsync -a --progress --size-only --exclude=".DS_Store" --exclude=".swp" --exclude=".Trash"  --exclude="logs/*" --exclude="xmlogs/*" /Users/Devric/Documents/notes/ /Volumes/backup/
```

Also,
if efficiency is a must for you, google for some --filter=+rs_/ uses

Comment: You are a legend! that's exactly the issues
didn't know that spaces makes a difference in bash!

Comment: Besides accepting the answer you can click the up arrow thingy to upvote it ;)

Comment: Isn't `-a` just short for `--archive` because archive starts with A?